# how to enable secure boot on ensonic h61

Tags: windows, bios

As everybody knows Windows 11 has been released. So, I am tiring to make my computer prepare for that. But, My Pc has not the minimum requirement. I have problem that my pc doesn't enabled **secure boot**. In the Bios settings in my pc dose not showing up the secure boot option.

My Pc's motherboard info:

**MotherBoard**: Esonic h61

Some Images of my bios:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Tyo.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d97EA.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fzz4.jpg

Comment: There is no answer to this question. Not enough information from Microsoft and what is available is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

> how to enable secure boot on ensonic h61

Based on the screenshots you have provided your system fails to meet multiple minimum requirements for Windows 11.

It’s unlikely that the requirements for Secure Boot and TPM 2.0 will be removed which means your current system is incompatible with Windows 11.

While there is always a small chance the CPU requirements for Windows 11 will be clarified, your system fails multiple major requirements for Windows 11, which are unlikely to be changed.

Windows 11 Insider Preview builds, will have lighter restrictions on the requirements, but the requirements for Windows 11 RTM will be strictly enforced.  Systems that don’t meet the minimum requirements will be forced to downgrade to Windows 10 once Windows 11 RTM is released.

> But, My Pc do not meet the minimum requirement. I have pro

Your machine fails to meet the current minimum requirements for Windows 11.  Your machine does not have any support for TPM 2.0, Secure Boot, and it doesn’t appear to even support UEFI based on the screenshots you provided.

Your processor also based on the chipset appears to be a 2nd or 3rd generation Intel Core processor fails to meet the minimum requirements.

> - Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with two or more cores on a [compatible 64-bit processor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements) or system on a chip (SoC).
> - System firmware: UEFI, Secure Boot capable.
> - TPM: Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0.

Source: [Windows 11 - Hardware Requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/windows-11-requirements#hardware-requirements)